# Emailjs just working sometimes with Microsoft Edge

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, web, contact-form

Hi I'm new to web development and I'm trying to send a simple  contact form using emailJS, it was working a week ago from my localhost and a hosting site from firebase but I don't know what happened that stopped working properly  and now only works sometimes from localhost in Microsoft edge browser. If I try to submit with one of the text-areas empty the window alert pops out but when I have all the fields it only reloads the page but doesn’t show the window alert that says ‘Email sent!’
I followed this tutorial to use EmailJS https://blog.mailtrap.io/react-send-email/#Sending_emails_with_EmailJS
I am developing the website with ReactJS so here are the functions of my contact form component, any help is appreciated! Thanks :D

This is where I handle the changes from the text-areas

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state ={
  name: '',
  email: '',
  message: '',
}

this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);
this.handleChangeMessage = this.handleChangeMessage.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);;
```

This is my summit part

```
handleChangeName(event) {
this.setState({name: event.target.value});
}
handleChangeEmail(event) {
this.setState({email: event.target.value});
}
handleChangeMessage(event) {;
this.setState({message: event.target.value});
}
handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const templateId = 'template_7HeYQshf';
 if(this.state.email === '' || this.state.name === '' || this.state.message === '')
 {
   window.alert('All fields are required.')
   window.location.reload();
 }
 else {
  this.sendFeedback(templateId, {message_html: this.state.message, from_name: this.state.name,
  reply_to: this.state.email})
 }
}   
sendFeedback (templateId, variables) {
window.emailjs.send(
  'gmail', templateId,
  variables
  ).then(res => {
    window.alert('Email sent!');  
    window.location.reload();      
  })
  // Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
  .catch(err => window.alert('something went wrong, please try again '))
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Issue with the following changes:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state ={
  name: '',
  email: '',
  message: '',
};
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

This is my new summit part

```
handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
};

handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
if(this.state.email === '' || this.state.name === '' || this.state.message === '')
{
  window.alert('All fields are required.')
  window.location.reload();
}
else {
  emailjs.send(
    "gmail",
    "template_7HeYQshf",
    {message_html: this.state.message, from_name: this.state.name, reply_to: this.state.email},
    "*****"
  )
  window.alert('Email sent!')
  window.location.reload();
 } 
}
```